# JQuery: How to select specific element of a class by data-, then use as target?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, contenteditable

I've modified code from this tutorial ( http://gazpo.com/2011/09/contenteditable/ Demo: http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/html5/contentEditable/ ) that will show more than one div of contenteditable div from a database, and through AJAX, save the changes of the modified .

Here's what the PHP produces: http://jsfiddle.net/fmdx/78rWQ/

```
    <div data-id="0" class="wrap"><!-- Content Wrapper -->
      <div data-id="0" class="status"></div>
    <div data-id="0" class="content">
    <p data-id="0" style="padding-left:7px;">
            <span data-id="0" style="padding-right:10px;">a)</span>
            <span data-id="0" data-primary="1" data-comcounted="0" data-showcom="1" data-fileno="CTTEST" data-part="1" class="editable" contenteditable="true">Compliance with the terms and conditions of the Clearwater Ordinance as currently set forth by the City of Sheboygan.</span></p>
        </div>
      <button data-id="0" class="save">Save</button>      
    </div>
```

Multiplied by how many rows within that table.

Here's the Jquery/Ajax:
        $(document).ready(function() {

```
    $(".save").click(function (e) {     
        //how do I narrow down these variables to that specific grouping being selected?
        var text = $('.editable').html();
        var primary_key = $('.editable').attr('data-primary');
        var showcom = $('.editable').attr('data-showcom');
        var comcounted = $('.editable').attr('data-comcounted');
        var part = $('.editable').attr('data-part');
        var fileno = $('.editable').attr('data-fileno');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            text: text,
            primary_key: primary_key,
            showcom: showcom,
            comcounted: comcounted,
            part: part,
            fileno: fileno              
            },              
            success:function (data) {

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $(".status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data saved successfully")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
                else
                {
                    $(".status")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
            }
        });   
    });

    $(".editable").click(function (e) {
        $(".save").show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $(".save").hide();  
    });
});
```

This, multiplied by however many rows that are returned from the database.

When one div is selected, every SAVE button appears, and when the data is saved, it shows the status bar for every div.

What I am trying to do is get the data-id attribute of the span that was selected so that it it is unique for the wrapper, status, contentedibable section, and that save bar. In a way, it is serving as the ID for the whole wrapped segment.How would I change the jquery/AJAX so that when that when a contenteditable div is selected, only that specific div will be modified, have the save button pop up on it, and have that status bar show (instead of every one showing)?

Comment: Did the below answer help you

Comment: I'm putting the code in, but it's not showing the status bar on save (error or successful).  Looking in the database, I'm also not seeing the changes so I'm going through the ajax to make sure I'm not trying to save this to a piece of lint.  But it seems you've got me pointed on the right track, just trying to work the kinks out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your selector specific to the current element in action.

i.e

`$('.save').show();` becomes `$(this).closest('.content').next(".save").show()`
`$('.editable').html();` becomes `$this.prev('.content').find('.editable')`
`$('.status')` becomes `$this.closest('.wrap').find(".status")`

JS:

```
$(".editable").click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.content').next(".save").show(); //<-- select the specific one
    e.stopPropagation();
});


 $(".save").click(function (e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $editable = $this.prev('.content').find('.editable'),
            text = $editable.html(),
            primary_key = $editable.data('primary'),
            showcom = $editable.data('showcom'),
            comcounted = $editable.data('comcounted'),
            part = $editable.data('part'),
            fileno = $editable.data('fileno');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                text: text,
                primary_key: primary_key,
                showcom: showcom,
                comcounted: comcounted,
                part: part,
                fileno: fileno
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var mg = "An error occured, the data could not be saved";
                if (data == '1') {
                    mg = "Data saved successfully";
            }
            $this.closest('.wrap').find(".status")
                .addClass("success")
                .html(mg)
                .fadeIn('fast')
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeOut('slow');
        }
        });
    });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4rBx/)**

Comment: Thanks!  I had to change the echo/json to point to save.php and voila, it works nicely (which explains why before it wouldn't show the status bar regardless of success or fail).

Comment: @fmdx Oh yes i had put it for testing in fiddler.

Comment: How would you modify the status bar in case of an error?  In the original tutorial they have the code, but since you've modified that if statement I can't seem to get it to work nicely (in the CSS there's a class to make the background of that status bar turn red when an error occurs, currently regardless of the message the status bar is green, which is a bit of a visual miscue for a user)

Comment: @fm oh i dint notice that you can just set up the class as well like the message. like this http://jsfiddle.net/Rx7gL/